# Intersection Between Two String Sets with Substring Compare

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++17

I know this is bike shedding but is there a way to get the set of strings C, between two (sorted) sets A,B of strings, where B is a sub string of A, with a complexity better than of `A.size * B.size * comp_substr`, as the naive solution I came up?

```
    std::copy_if(devices.cbegin(), devices.cend(),
                          std::back_inserter(ports),
                          [&comport_keys] (const auto& v) {
        return std::any_of(comport_keys.begin(),comport_keys.end(), [&v](auto& k) {
           return v.find(k) != std::string::npos;
        });
    });
```

The easier case of just where B is a string of A, with `std::set_intersection` would be pretty simple with a complexity of `(A.size + B.size) * comp_substr`, with would be even better if one had to sort it before `(n * log(n))`, but I don't know how to write the compare function for it, or rather the sort of both.

```
    #define BOOST_TEST_MODULE My Test

    #include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>

    #include <vector>
    #include <string>
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <iterator>
    #include <set>

    BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(TEST) {
        std::vector<std::string> devices{
                "tty1",
                "ttyOfk",
                "ttyS05",
                "bsd",
        }, ports{};

        const std::set<std::string> comport_keys{
                "ttyS",
                "ttyO",
                "ttyUSB",
                "ttyACM",
                "ttyGS",
                "ttyMI",
                "ttymxc",
                "ttyAMA",
                "ttyTHS",
                "ircomm",
                "rfcomm",
                "tnt",
                "cu",
                "ser",
        };

        std::sort(devices.begin(), devices.end());
        std::set_intersection(devices.cbegin(), devices.cend(),
                              comport_keys.cbegin(), comport_keys.cend(),
                              std::back_inserter(ports),
                              [&comport_keys] (auto a, auto b) {
            return a.find(b) != std::string::npos; //This is wrong
        });

        const std::vector<std::string>test_set {
                "ttyOfk",
                "ttyS05",
        };

        BOOST_TEST(ports == test_set);
    }
```

Comment: Yes, you can build a generalised suffix tree on B and query it with each string in A to solve this in O(|A|+|B|) time.  But this will not be worth the implementation complexity until at least one of these sets is several tens or hundreds of thousands of times larger than in your example code.

Comment: BTW, I would not call looking for a better algorithm "bikeshedding".  Debating whether to use lambdas or manual loops to implement it would be an example of bikeshedding.

Comment: Is `comport_keys` known at compile time? transform it in regex might be a solution then.

Comment: Do you want "sub-string" match, or just "start with"?

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes it is, but a regex with all that alternatives has at least the same complexity

Comment: @Jarod42 Substring

Comment: @Superlokkus: state machine of the regex would factorize your common `tty`. I would expect lower complexity (but for time, you have to measure, as usual) (and its `comp_substr` would be better than `std::string::find(const std::string&)`).

Comment: Put A into a suffix array. Check each string in B, whether the suffix array of A contains it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say we have two sets of strings: A and B. B contains a set of potential prefixes for the strings in A. So we want to take each element a from A and try to match it with all potential prefixes of B.
If we find a matching prefix, we store our result a in C. The trivial solution works in O(|A| |B|). You ask: Can we optimize this?

You said, B is already sorted. Then we can build a generalised prefix tree on B in linear time and query it with each string in A to solve it in O(|A|+|B). The problem is, sorting B takes O(|B| log|B|) and the tree is non-trivial.

So I provide a simple solution with O(|A| log|B|) which is more efficient than O(|A|+|B|) if |A| is small, like in your example. B is still assumed to be sorted (the sorting is really the upper bound here...).

```
bool
validate_prefixes(const std::multiset<std::string>& keys) {
    auto itb = keys.begin(), it = itb;
    if(it == keys.end()) return false; //no keys
    for(++it; it != keys.end(); ++it) {
        if( (*it).find(*itb) != std::string::npos ) return false; //redundant keys
        itb++;
    }
    return true;
}

bool
copy_from_intersecting_prefixes(const std::vector<std::string>& data, 
                                std::multiset<std::string>& prefix_keys,
                                std::vector<std::string>& dest, bool check = false) {
    if(check && !validate_prefixes(prefix_keys)) return false;

    for(auto it_data = data.begin(); it_data != data.end(); ++it_data) {
        auto ptr = prefix_keys.insert(*it_data), ptrb = ptr;
        if(ptrb != prefix_keys.begin()) {  //if data is at the start, there is no prefix
            if( (*ptr).find(*(--ptrb)) != std::string::npos ) dest.push_back(*it_data);
        }
        prefix_keys.erase(ptr);
    } //Complexity: O(|data|) * O( log(|prefix_keys|) ) * O(substr) = loop*insert*find
    return check;
}

//.... in main()
std::multiset<std::string> tmp(comport_keys.begin(), comport_keys.end()); //copy const    
copy_from_intersecting_prefixes(devices, tmp, ports);
```

`validate_prefixes` enforces a precondition. It checks if we have at least one valid prefix and that the keys are not self-matching. E.g. we could have keys `cu` and `cu2`, but `cu` is a prefix for `cu2`, so they can't be both valid prefixes, either `cu` is too general or `cu2` too specific. If we try to match `cu3` with `cu` and `cu2` this is inconsistent. Here `validate_prefixes(comport_keys)` returns `true`, but it might be nice to check it automatically.

`copy_from_intersecting_prefixes` does the actual asked work. It iterates over A, and puts a inside the ordered B. The prefix is smaller than prefix+ending, so if a corresponding prefix exists, it will occur before a in B. Because the keys are not self-matching, we know that the prefix will precede a in B. So we decrement the iterator from a and compare. Note that prefix might equal a, so we need multiset.